# How to avoid picture from being copied

Tags: copy, photo

I am onto a photo project. Dynamically added a watermark in the large picture preview. But someone with general idea can manipulate the link and get the original picture. Disabling Right button seems to be useless. In this case what can be the appropriate solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable any access to original pictures. Make server script that receives picture's ID (or name) and sets watermark before picture will be shown. And make your application such way that this script only can access images by users. If manipulation with link allows users to have unauthorized access, then it looks like you have problems with architecture of project.